# Speaker veneer challenge (wood repair)

Tags: wood, wooden-furniture

So I bought great but slightly damaged speakers and I would like to restore them, I understand they won't look like new but I would like to try my best.

The damage:
[image]

The wood texture detail:
[image]

I was thinking of using some [wood filler/wax](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_odkw=dark%20wood%20wax%20filler&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xdark%20wood%20wax%20filler%20kit&_nkw=dark%20wood%20wax%20filler%20kit&_sacat=0), do you have any experience you could share? Also I was thinking of creating an negative imprint to recreate the texture, what material could I us? Maybe silicon? Some form of dental acrylic?

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I recently replaced the door handle on my front door.  There were two holes left from the old handle.  I filled them with Plastic Wood, then sanded flush.  Then, I took a awl and mimicked the grain pattern.  It looks spectacular.  After priming and painting, my mother could not even see where the hole was.   You can do it!